# what's the optimum way to implement push_back without overhead

Tags: c++, performance, circular-list

I'm trying to implement a Queue where you pass to it an Object to be added to the Queue.

```
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node *next, *prev;
};    
// Push data to the back of the list.
template <class T> T& CircularQueue<T>::push_back(const T&& new_data)
{
    Node* new_node = new Node();
    new_node->data = std::move(new_data);
    link_node(new_node, m_head);
    return new_node->data;
}
```

The problem with my current approach is there is too much overhead (as i come from C these things bothers me). for example image i will add an object from MyClass:

```
CircularQueue<MyClass> list;
list.push_back(MyClass(arg1, arg2));
```

The first problem is that the MyClass needs to have a constructor without argument to be used in `Node* new_node = new Node();` since creating a Node structure will call the constructor of the object inside it which is MyClass. i tried with std::vector and it didn't require this.

The second problem is too much overhead, `list.push_back(MyClass(arg1, arg2));` will create an rvalue object in the stack then send to `push_back`, it then creates a new object (with no argument list) in the heap then move all of its  members to the new object using move assignment, is there any faster solution ?

Comment: `const T&& new_data` will just turn this into a copy. No move will happen

Comment: yeah but it will be moved in `new_node->data = std::move(new_data);`.
given that the object has move assignment.

Comment: No it will not. You can't move from `const` objects. that is why rvalue references are never `const`

Comment: No it won't. The const negates move semantics entirely

Comment: Instead of having a member `data` of the type `T`, you could have a member `data` being the type `char[sizeof(T)]`, then use placement-new to copy/move the object (this is somewhat simplified what `std::vector` does). Then the type doesn't have to be default-constructible.

Comment: the first and biggest problem I see is that you allocate memory for each element you push

Comment: And what is the reason that you don't add a constructor to `struct Node` with an argument `T`. And do `template <class T> T& CircularQueue<T>::push_back( T&& new_data)
{
    Node* new_node = new Node(std::move(new_data));` ?

Comment: @Waqar Oh right, that makes sense, now if remove the that const, how to solve the moving overhead ? or is it acceptable ?

Comment: @Some programmer dude that seems reasonable but there still will be an overhead from copying from the stack to the heap.

Comment: @t.niese i think that helps, i mean instead of creating an object then using move assignment we can use move constructor directly.

Comment: @Sopel  is there a better solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a function to work with move semantics and copy semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467791/how-to-define-a-function-to-work-with-move-semantics-and-copy-semantics) The simplest way to make `push_back` efficient without writing a ton of code is to make the parameter by-value. But you may as well provide an emplace, which doesn't make your code much more complicated (just implement `template<typename T> T &CircularQueue<T>::push_back(T const &x) { return emplace_back(x); }`) and is more flexible *and* is more efficient.

Comment: Yes, just use value parameter and let the move constructor handle things.

Comment: You can grow capacity of your queue at the rate of `*2`, so that you will not have to allocate memory everytime you push back, that will reduce performance overhead. This is what `std::vector` does.

Comment: so i think doing it using emplace_back will not double the capacity of the queue, right ? but i'm still curious why i shouldn't allocate memory for each element i push as @Sopel  stated (i consider he's talking about heap allocation)

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE 1. Heap allocation dominates push_back time for simple types. 2. It becomes suspect to memory fragmentation and, most importantly, locality of reference which harms performance due to cache misses. The solution is to use contiguous chunk (std::vector) or chunks (std::deque) of memory. To make it work you will have to get familiar with uninitialized storage and placement new. Someone also mentioned scaling factor of `*2` on reallocation, in theory this is the worst factor because the previous memory can't be reused (2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^(n-1) < 2^n). Usually smaller factors are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can emplace_back your Node

```
template <class T> 
class CircularQueue {
    template<typename... U>
    T &emplace_back(U&&... u)
    {
       Node *new_node = new Node{{std::forward<U>(u)...}}; // <data is created here
        // link_node(new_node, m_head);
       return new_node->data;
    }
};
void foo() {
    CircularQueue<Data> x;
    // Do not create a Data, pass the parameters you need to create
    x.emplace_back(10, 20);
    // If you actually need to, you can of course copy or move an existing Data
    Data y(20, 30);
    x.emplace_back(y); // copies y
    x.emplace_back(std::move(y)); // moves y
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/z68q77

Comment: I think that's the best solution, though the code in compiler explorer link you posted is optimized away.

Comment: `new Node{{std::forward<U>(u)...}}` will behave in unpredictable ways with classes like `std::vector`. It needs to be replaced with `new Node{T(std::forward<U>(u)...)}`.